CloudWatch log parsing
I want to parse the log events in the following format in AWS CloudWatch Insights using Cloudwatch queries for visulaisation of my log data.
Example:
{
    "Start Time": "2024-10-11 12:28:27:921384",
    "End Time": "2024-10-11 12:29:33:254049",
    "Duration": 65.332665,
    "Job Category": "Batch",
    "Job Type": "Glue",
    "Status": {
        "Success": "Job completed successfully"
    },
    "Transformations": [
        {
            "Transformation Name": "Spark Session",
            "Start Time": "2024-10-11 12:28:28:187513",
            "End Time": "2024-10-11 12:28:32:017445",
            "Duration": 3.829932,
            "Details": "Creating spark session"
        },
        {
            "Transformation Name": "Snowflake Connection",
            "Start Time": "2024-10-11 12:28:32:018356",
            "End Time": "2024-10-11 12:28:32:171764",
            "Duration": 0.153408,
            "Details": "Establishing Snowflake Connection"
        },
        {
            "Transformation Name": "Source DF",
            "Start Time": "2024-10-11 12:28:32:185737",
            "End Time": "2024-10-11 12:28:38:780156",
            "Duration": 6.594419,
            "Details": "Creating Source DataFrame"
        },
        {
            "Transformation Name": "DF Batch to webhook",
            "Start Time": "2024-10-11 12:29:21:934966",
            "End Time": "2024-10-11 12:29:33:253845",
            "Duration": 11.318879,
            "Details": "Converting the DataFrame into json and send to webhook",
            "Info": {
                "Number of rows": 6,
                "Number of Batches": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}

I wanted to write a query to parse these transformation duration and details but I'm unable to do so because of the nested nature of the log events. Appreciate any help.
